# Is it possible to run cloudbees builds from a fixed IP address?

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I've been using Cloudbees DEV@Cloud to build and test my code. Now I want to automate the deployment of my applications to Amazon AWS.

To deploy the applications I scp files to Amazon and use ssh sessions to start the applications. This works just fine, but I'm force to allow ssh connections to my Amazon AWS instances.
Is it possible to run the Cloudbees builds from a fixed IP address, so I don't have to allow ssh access to the AWS instances from every IP address?

Answer (score 0):

No, DEV@cloud slaves are drawn from an elastic pool of machines (in EC2, currently), so you cannot fix a particular IP address. If you need to restrict access to a resource which builds must use, you can configure [VPN service](http://dev-at-cloud-docs.cloudbees.com/docs/dev-at-cloud-docs-1.1/JenkinsVPN.html) instead.

Comment: For EC2 it is possible to use Elastic IP Addresses. So I thought it might be possible to assign a static IP to the slaves. Any idea whether this is a possibility?

Comment: Actually it is possible. When the enterprise version is chosen, it is possible to a an on-premise slave. The on-premise slave can be a AWS instance that is privately hosted and has an Elastic IP.

Comment: Yes, that is the other option, though it means that you have to manage your own slaves.